# how do we go about building an "email client"?

Tags: web-services, web-applications, email

I'm wondering how do we go about building an "email client" that is on the web.. or is it even possible to have people connect to my "email client" from their gmails/hotmails/yahoo mails and read their emails from my client?

Comment: The reason for the down votes is that you are not mentioning what/how you would like to build it.

Comment: @Benny can you please stop removing all the `getting-started` tags from questions? Most are valid, they are being rejected in review. If you don't like the tag then raise it in meta.

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst It has been raised in meta, it is also a meta tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your language of choice you'll find that there are both IMAP and POP libraries that you can use to access email accounts online.

The IMAP protocol is available [here](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3501.html) if you want to find out more about the details of IMAP, it is a fairly complex system, with [pop](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1939) providing an easier, though less popular alternative.

Comment: heys cool do you know of any tutorials specifically targeted on this issue (building a standalone email client for yourself/your friends that can read your emails on gmail/hotmail/yahoo mail etc)

Comment: @Pacerier I've not come across anything — it's quite a complicated piece of software to build.